# Parse open source queries are slower than Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I switched over to Parse open source on AWS. I ran my app and it works fine on the same code, it just runs a lot slower then when it was on Parse.com. So I tested to see if it was my database on mLab. I upgraded that but it did not make a difference. Am I the only one having this issue or is there other people having this same issue?